# http not redirect to https

Tags: .htaccess, https

How would I write the.htaccess file to https://www.domain.com
example:

```
domain.com => https://www.domain.com
www.domain.com => https://www.domain.com
https://domain.com => https://www.domain.com
http://www.domain.com => https://www.domain.com
```

this is my htaccess:

```
# Use PHP5.4 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#  Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mydomain\.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

I add the next code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# add https to domain.
   RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

but my domain remain www.domain.com not https://www.domain.com .
what I should change ?

many thanks.

Comment: Downvoter - if you flag a question and downvote it - at least write a comment and explain!

Comment: I want that, when some user enter to my website he will get https not http no meter what address he will type, all the string redirect the user to https: //www.domain.com many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you should do is add the following to `http.conf` or to `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

If you edit `http.conf` you should restart Apache afterwards:

```
service httpd restart
```